# <body> height extends on internet explorer 8 and below

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The `<body>` height of my homepage extends to about 200% on earlier IE. The website is http://www.graetz-ran.co.il/.

Answer (score 0):

After `<div id="fp-gallery"></div>` get rid of `<span class="push-h"></span>`